Extracting and aggregating a state of lower components / Avoiding rendering
I have a question regarding react state. I'm still a beginner but - I have a table with three columns. In two of these, I have input fields. I set it up each row is a component and has its own state. When the user changes the inputs in rows, the state is changed, the ID of a row/product is added to the state object as well. After the user is done, he clicks on the button "save" and the whole thing is transferred to the SQL DB.
And there lies the question - how to extract the state of the of the rows when the button is clicked? There is an App component in which I have a table component and on the same level, I have a button component. Right now, when the input is changed, it is saved to the global state as well, which is on the same level as the App. The problem is that each change of the input triggers rerender of a whole component. I didn't find how to do this better way, so the App component is not rerendered each time. I know the problem is triggered by the change of the state of the App component, but I don't know how to solve this another way. I tried to use a custom hook for context, but the problem is still the same... It is the props or state anyway which triggers the rerender still.
git cd
I created an example which illustrates my problem pretty well.
Here is the link to the stackblitz environment. In the console it is easy to see what is happening:
Stackblitz example
Thank you for any help. ChatGPT is not helping much  This has to be a common issue, either I'm dumb or I'm missing something. Sometime I got an error: Too many re-renders.
lifting the state up, useContext, useRef - which actually worked and didn't cause rerendering, but I don't know if this is the right solution.

In React data flows in one direction, parent to child. Move the state you want to aggregate over to a common ancestor, e.g. the parent, and pass it down as props to descendants, e.g  the children. See Sharing state between components for more complete details. In legacy terms, yes, this is the old "lifting state up" pattern.

@DrewReese It won't solve the problem. Every time something is written in the input field, it updates the parent state causing a rerender of the whole component. I don't know tbh if this is normal behaviour of web apps, but I don't think so.

That's React... (1) enqueue state update, (2) component re-rendered to see updated state. Is there some issue or problem with your app rerendering?

@DrewReese There is. I wouldn't be bothered by this re-rendering issue, but sometimes, when a user changes inputs a lot, an error appears saying "Too many renders".

I think, in my original case, since every row has its state ( there are 10 rows for example ) on every change of an input, it triggers the rendering of 10 components(rows) which causes the re-render error. And all is because of the global state which I need to be able to send the data to the DB. What I want to achieve is to rerender only the row which was edited. And then - on button click I want to extract the states, aggregate them to an array and send data to the backend.

I see you've placed a bunch of console logs in the component bodies of these components, these are not an accurate measure of component renders as these are all unintentional side-effects. Can you [edit] your post to include a complete and more accurate [mcve] of the relevant code you are working with (in the post), and include your exact reproduction steps, so it's clear to readers what you are dealing with?

The easiest solution to solve re-rendering of the whole app on every single user input is to use either throttle or debounce.
I updated ChildComponent to use debounce, but left SecondComponent unchanged to show the difference, but you can apply the same changes to SecondComponent. Here is the updated ChildComponent that uses use-debounce library:
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { useDebounce } from 'use-debounce';
import { useTextContext } from './TextContext';

const ChildComponent = () => {
  const { childText, setChildText } = useTextContext();
  // I added the local state for the input to prevent updating "childText" on each user input
  const [localChildText, setLocalChildText] = useState(childText);
  const [childTextDedounced] = useDebounce(localChildText, 1000);

  useEffect(() => {
    // Prevent redundant "setChildText" call if the value in the context("childText") and local("localChildText") are the same
    if (childText === localChildText) {
      return;
    }

    // Once the "childTextDedounced" is changed, I update "childText" through "setChildText"
    setChildText(childTextDedounced);
  }, [childTextDedounced]);

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    setLocalChildText(event.target.value);
    console.log('ChildComponent handleChange - childText:', event.target.value);
  };

  console.log('ChildComponent re-rendered');

  return (
    <>
      <input type="text" value={localChildText} onChange={handleChange} />
    </>
  );
};

export default ChildComponent;

Here is the updated Stackblitz example
